# Vue watcher data not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a watcher on a value of an object, I do an api call to get some data if the value is true, but it seems like the data in my local state is updating a tick too late.

If the condition is true nothing is set and I switch it back to false then the data is being set.

This is my code:

```
props: {
  simulation: {type: Simulation, default: () => new Simulation()}
}
data() {
  return {
    loadedStores: []
  }
},
watch: {
  'simulation.fetch': function () {
      if (this.simulation.fetch) {
        axios.get(`some-url`)
          .then((response) => {
            this.loadedStores = response.data.data;
          })
      }
  }
}
```

simulation.fetch updates to true or false through a select option in my interface.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I've tried wrapping it with `this.$nextTick(() => {})` but that doesn't weem to be doing anything

Comment: Please share also how you have set the `data` options in the post.

Comment: @palaѕн I added the data options

Comment: So, which `data` option are you actually watching here?

Comment: `simulation.fetch` is not reactive as it is not declared in `data` function

Comment: @palaѕн simulation is a prop that's passed to my component. simulation.fetch updates to true or false through a select option in the interface

Comment: @HarshalPatil I edited OP with more info on what simulation.fetch is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [deep watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) for this so that the callback will be called whenever any of the watched object properties change regardless of their nested depth:

```
watch: {
  simulation: {
    handler: function() {
      console.log(this.simulation.fetch)
      if (this.simulation.fetch) {
        // axios call here
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Your watch code would have worked fine, if `fetch` was defined in the data option and if `simulation` was not a prop actually like:

```
data() {
  return {
    loadedStores: [],
    simulation: {
      fetch: false 
    }
  }
},
```

This change detection caveat is explained in details here

- [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem and the only issue I see is when `Simulation.fetch` starts with `true`. watcher doesn't get called and for that you might use `mounted()` hook

```js
class Simulation {
  constructor() {
    this.fetch = true;
    this.timeout = 1000;
    this.handle = null;
    
    const loop = () => {
      this.fetch = !this.fetch;
    
      this.handle = setTimeout(loop, this.timeout);  
    }
    
    this.handle = setTimeout(loop, this.timeout);
  }
}

Vue.component("test", {
  template: `<div><div :key="item" v-for="item in loadedStores">{{item}}</div></div>`,
  props: {
    simulation: {
      type: Simulation,
      default: () => new Simulation()
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loadedStores: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'simulation.fetch': function () {
      this.tryGetData();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    tryGetData() {
      if (this.simulation.fetch) {
        this.loadedStores = [...Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).keys()]
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.tryGetData();
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
```